# Matlab Container.Map behavior vs Dictionary

Tags: matlab, dictionary, containers

I had to remove in my existing script, all dictionary structures to container.Map because I must run my app on old matlab version (<=R2012b)

I have a call member on an instance like this :

```
% Declaration of container map
app.MC = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');

% Create first instance of Monte Carlo object with the key -15. 
% Monte_Carlo is a class herited from Handle
app.MC(-15) = Monte_Carlo(Nb_Iterations_par_depointage, consigne_depointage_y);

% Call member on Monte_Carlo instance
app.MC(-15).Enregistre_Reference_Dephasage_Secteur(a, b);
```

When I execute this, I get the following error on the last line

```
Too many output arguments.
```

But if I replace the declaration by

```
% Declaration of container map
app.MC = dictionary;
```

All works fine.

I checked the types, and in both cases `class(app.MC(-15))` returns `'Monte_Carlo'`

If I proceed in 2 times with an intermediate variable which sotres the `app.MC(-15)` instance, it works :

```
% Declaration of container map
app.MC = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
    
% Create first instance of Monte Carlo object with the key -15
app.MC(-15) = Monte_Carlo(Nb_Iterations_par_depointage, consigne_depointage_y);
    
% Intermediate variable in order to call member with container.Map
Z = app.MC(-15);

% Now I can do that, and it works 
Z.Enregistre_Reference_Dephasage_Secteur(a, b);
```

Do you know why I can access to the member of the object directly with dictionary, and I can't with container.Map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because of the way that `containers.Map` is implemented. It’s one of the many issues with it that prompted them to add `dictionary`. You’re not doing anything wrong.

If

```
Z.Enregistre_Reference_Dephasage_Secteur(a, b);
```

modifies `Z`, then `Z` must be a handle object for this to work. If it’s not a handle object (the class is derived from `handle`) then you need to write the `Z` back into the container after modifying it, because you modified a copy:

```
Z = app.MC(-15);
Z = Z.make_a_change(a, b);
app.MC(-15) = Z;
```

(But do note that in your code, Z is either a handle object or it’s not modified, so that code is always correct.)

Comment: And there is no way to get a pointer of app.MC(-15) in order to not work on a copy ?

In my case, Z is an object of class Monte_Carlo which is derived from handle, so it should work

Comment: @LnlB MATLAB does not do pointers, the handle object is the closest you’ll get. The `Z` refers to the same object as `app.MC(-15)`.